# $I,J$ left minimal ideals of a ring with $1\neq 0$ then $IJ=0$ or $IJ\cong J$ as left $R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

The exercise is the following:

> Let $R$ be a ring with unity $1\neq 0$ and let $I,J$ be minimal left ideals of $R$ (A left ideal $I$ is said to be a minimal left ideal if $I\neq 0$ and for every left ideal $J$ such that $0\subset J\subset I$, either $J=0$ or $J=I$).
>
> Prove that $IJ=0$ or $IJ\cong J$ as left $R$-modules.

I don't understand the second conclusion. As $I,J$ are left-ideals then $IJ$ (which consist in all the finite sums of elements of the form $ij$ with $i\in I, j\in J$) is a left ideal contained in $J$, so by hypothesis $IJ=0$ or $IJ=J$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed by hypothesis, either $IJ=0$ or $I=J=IJ$.

Comment: @Ale Tolcachier, Your reasoning is correct for me.

Comment: @pigeon, Why by hypotesis would be $I=J$? Recall that $I$ is only a left-ideal, then not necessarily $IJ\subset I$.